# Running plugins with NRPE as root: NRPE unable to read output

Tags: centos6, nagios, nrpe

I have a problem with nagios and NRPE and I can't resolve it.

I've already tried.

```
# grep "nrpe_user=" /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
nrpe_user=nrpe
```

NRPE is running as the user nrpe. So I added this lines to visudo:

```
Defaults:nrpe !requiretty
nrpe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_jboss_files
```

I edited my nagios nrpe.cfg:

```
command[check_jboss_files]=sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_jboss_files
```

But if I try to run the command from the Nagios server I get the following:

```
# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 1.2.3.4 -c check_jboss_files
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

The script was running as expected when launched locally, even when running as user nrpe:

```
# sudo sudo -s -u nrpe
bash-4.2$ sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_jboss_files
JBOSS Files: 2049
WARNING - JBOSS Files: 2049
```

Without sudo the script is working on nagios server, but must work with sudo to give good results. What I missed? I've probably tried everything and I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: does NRPE log anything useful to syslog?

Comment: Nothing special @Keith :( 

`Sep 19 20:18:08 idontknow nrpe[10286]: Host is asking for command 'check_jboss_files' to be run...`

`Sep 19 20:18:08 idontknow nrpe[10286]: Running command: sudo usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_jboss_files`

`Sep 19 20:18:08 idontknow nrpe[10286]: Command completed with return code 3 and output:`

`Sep 19 20:18:08 idontknow nrpe[10286]: Return Code: 3, Output: NRPE: Unable to read output`

`Sep 19 20:18:08 idontknow nrpe[10286]: Connection from  closed.`

Answer (score 1):

I faced with a very similar situation recently and the solution was to configure selinux to allow sudo access.

Follow [this](https://www.certdepot.net/selinux-diagnose-policy-violations/) article and you'll find out what to do.

For me this worked on CentOS 7.4:

1. `yum install -y setroubleshoot-server`
2. Search the violation in audit log
3. Use audit2why
4. Follow its suggestion

My violation:

```
$ grep -m 1 type=AVC.*sudo /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
type=AVC msg=audit(1525359549.889:211763): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=127488 comm="check_d" path="/usr/bin/sudo" dev="dm-0" ino=67120340 scontext=system_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:sudo_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Was caused by:
The boolean nagios_run_sudo was set incorrectly.
Description:
Allow nagios to run sudo

Allow access by executing:
# setsebool -P nagios_run_sudo 1
```

Running the suggested command solved my problem.